# Notepad++ highlighting anything between two square brackets

Tags: regex, text, notepad++, file-manipulation

I have a document containing a series of strings between hundreds of `[]` and I want to highlight the strings and copy the information into a spreadsheet.

I have attempted using the `Find` tool but cannot figure out the regex expression

The final goal of this would be to be able to copy the information in one go into a new file, or highlight it and copy into an excel spreadsheet.

Text file something like:

```
>X_343435353.3 words like foo bar [Wanted text]
TGATGATGCCATGCTAGCCATCGACTAGCGACTAGCATCGACTAGCATCAGCTACGACTAGCATCGACTACGA
>XP_543857836.3 other information [Text that I want]
TAGCATCGACTAGCTACTACCTGAGCGAGAAATTTTGGCTATCGACATCGACTATCGAGCACAGCTAGGAATT
>NP_3843875938.2 interesting words [Third desired text]
ATCGCATAGCGCGCTTAGAAGGCCTTAGAGGCATCATCTATCGAGCGACGATATCGCGAGGCAGCGCTATACC
```

The ouput I desire is as follows:

```
Wanted text
Text that I want
Third desired text
```

I am not sure if it is possible to do this in Notepad++ or if you need to use a cmd/shell tool to do it. I am using a Windows 10. The thought was that it may be possible to highlight all of the desired text with a regex that can then be copied elsewhere.

Comment: Could you give a sample text and expected result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To match just the text and not the brackets:

```
(?<=\[).*?(?=\])
```

Example:

[image: Notepad++ search example with OP example text]

To delete everything in a document and leave just the wanted text on each line:

1. Set the cursor at the start of the document.
2. Macro, Start recording.
3. Ctrl-F (Find), `.*?\[`, Select regular expression and `.` matches newline.
4. Click <kbd>Find Next</kbd> and close the dialog.
5. Delete the highlighted text.
6. Ctrl-F (Find), `\]`, Select regular expression and `.` matches newline.
7. Click <kbd>Find Next</kbd> and close the dialog.
8. Hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> to delete the highlighted text.
9. Macro, Stop recording.
10. Macro, Run a macro multiple times, select Until end of file.
11. Click <kbd>Run</kbd>.

Result:

```
Wanted text
Text that I want
Third desired text
```

You'll need to delete the last bit after the final match (if any) once the macro completes.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this expression,

```
.*\[(.*?)\][\s\S]+?([\r\n]|$)
```

with a replacement of `$1\n` also might work.

The expression is explained on the top right panel of [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/Ki6zvs/1/) if you wish to explore/simplify/modify it.

Answer (score 0):

This one is working fine for me ....

Find what: `>.*?\[(.*?)\]\n.*`
Replace with: `$1`